# After install xubuntu 16, starting gives errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, xubuntu, 16.04

The installation procedure was completely successful, but starting the new OS brings a lot of errors and blocks. Here some of the messages I see:

```
 Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it
 Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found
 Try pass init = option to kernel
 See Linux documentation/init.txt
```

I didn't find anything useful in this init.txt

I installed first besides Ubuntu 14.04, and this had this problem.
And secondly, I installed on a clean disk, which ended up with the same result.

Can I do something about it?

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it` shows that it's certainly not installed successfully. Please

1. [verify the integrity of the installation medium](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) and
2. see [How do I install Ubuntu?](/q/6328/175814) and install Xubuntu again from scratch.

Comment: That is what I did several times with the same result.

Comment: Alright, I updated to include a very recommended verification step (in case you haven't done that yet).

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!